# Displaying information from two tables in one grid view

Tags: php, yii

I have two tables in my database which are needed for in displaying a grid based table of info. Currently the code I have only displays the information for one table (Code below)

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'aux-room-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'room',
        'capacity',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

I since I have capacity I also would like to get the occupancy, based on how many rows there are associated to a room number which is in my second table. I know that without using PHP this may seem fairly simply, but I am new to Yii and do not understand how I can perform a count on another model. To find the occupancy I would need to use the room# which is the first column of table 1.

Simply put: I need to count() the rows associated with a room number from the first column. I need to display the original tables contents of room and capacity, but with occupancy in between these two columns. How would I do this using Yii?

SQL for the two tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cs_people`.`aux_room` (
  `room` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `capacity` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`room`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cs_people`.`room_desk` (
  `userid` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,
  `room` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  `desk` VARCHAR(250) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`) ,
  INDEX `room_desk.room_idx` (`room` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `room_desk.userid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userid` )
    REFERENCES `cs_people`.`people` (`userid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `room_desk.room`
    FOREIGN KEY (`room` )
    REFERENCES `cs_people`.`aux_room` (`room` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Did you read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query ?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this it would be best to use relations within your yii model. [Read this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) and implement the necessary relations on your models. Below is an example in yii of how you can show a count from a related model using the relation. In my project this is showing the number of users of a given type next to the list of user types.

In my project the below file lives in views/usertype/admin.php as it is for the admin view grid, the same would be applicable for an index view.

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id' => 'user-type-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'template' => '{items}',
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'name',
        array('header' => 'Users', 'value' => 'count($data->users)'),
        array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

The $model variable is passed from the UserType controller's actionAdmin() method. Gii should set this up for you. You can see that using the $data variable inside quotes in the columns array will give you access to the properties of each individual record. In this example it accesses the UserType record's 'users' relation and counts the number of related users.

These relations remove the need to the write any complex SQL. Yii will query the data and perform all the neccessary joins for you.

Comment: This is what i would have answered also.

Comment: I should add that this example uses the bootstrap extension TbGridBView. You may need to change the class and widget name to zii.widgets.grid.CGridView. It should function more or less the same.

Comment: aux_room table is does not have a relation with room_desk. I am getting the main content from the aux_room. room_desk is like the an object of aux_room. room_desk is assigned to a user where the room field is associated to the aux_room. I'm not sure if I can still apply relationships due to do. I will post the sql for the two tables after this comment.

Comment: List all of the relevant tables and objects, provided your data schema makes sense, I'm sure we can come up with a relationship structure that allows you access to all of this information. It sounds like you probably need a seperate table that handles the assignment of desks to users.

Comment: For example you should have the following tables: room, user, desk, room_desk, desk_user. Map the many to many relations and you can get at desks in a room using $room->desks and the users on a desk using $desk->users. You can even make a virtual attribute on the room table that counts the users foreach() of its ->desks and returns the total.

Comment: Here is what this section of the database looks like: http://i.imgur.com/hTi4SIs.png

Answer (score 0):

Not a Yii specific solution, but personally, I'd use a view to get that data straight from the database.

Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW rooms_with_occupancy 
AS
    SELECT r.*, count(o.*) as occupant_count
    FROM rooms r
    LEFT JOIN occupancy o ON o.room_id = r.id
    GROUP BY r.id
```

Now when binding the widget you'd use the `rooms_with_occupancy` view instead of the `rooms` table.

See [the official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) for more info on creating views.

Comment: One of the main benefits of using views is reusability.  There are also performance benefits, ease of use and increased readability

Comment: I have never actually used views before. How would I modify this to work with a table named aux_room which has a foreign key in the table room_desk. You can think of the room_desk being an object of aux_room, in that every room has multiple desks assigned to people. I am little confused how I could modify this view code to work with this.

Comment: @Fogest, Just write the select statement the way you would and add the `CREATE VIEW view_name AS" line above it. I'd be glad to do it for you but only if I have the complete create statements of both tables, or at least the foreign key definitions, Wouldn't want to write something specific and then have it not work.

Comment: SQL added into original post.